# Prediction from autoKrige in package automap

Tags: r

I am trying to predict a model calculated by `autoKrige` to new_data.

In my case, new_data are the cells of a raster, computed in R package `raster`.

`autoKrige` will not predict to my raster:

```
library(automap)
afvg1 <- autoKrige(Sand~x+y, sand2utmOGR, 
                   model = c("Sph", "Exp", "Gau", "Ste"), new_data=rasta2)

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature "RasterLayer"’
```

How do I convert my raster to a format that `autoKrige` can use for prediction?

Comment: Can you make a fully reproducible example?

Comment: Can ppl explain their close votes? Its a poorly expressed Q, but very much on the topic of R programming - vote down and comment for clarification rather than close surely?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess... for some raster `r`, make `SpatialPoints`, use that for `new_data`, feed predictions back into the raster.

```
nd = as(r,"SpatialPoints")
fvg1<-autoKrige(blah blah, new_data=nd)
r[]=(predictions from fvg1)
```

I'll make my answer cut-n-paste runnable when your question is.